# List the elements of the smallest set of pairs which needs to be added to R to form an equivalence relation, R∗

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Suppose R = {(1, 1),(1, 4),(1, 5),(2, 2),(2, 7),(3, 3),(3, 6)} is a
> relation on the set A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}

Q: List the elements of the smallest set of pairs which needs to be added to
R to form an equivalence relation, R∗

Attempt:

No clue how to answer this. What does equivalence mean? Would the smallest set be (1,1)? Would equivalence be (4,1), (5,1) (2,2) (7,2), (3,3), (6,3) etc etc? Not sure.

Comment: Read the definition of [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) if you don't know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An equivalence relation has to be reflexive wich means $(a,a) \in R$, for all $a \in R$, therefore you have to add $(4,4),(5,5),(6,6)$ to $R$.

It also has to be symmmetric wich means: for all $a,b \in R$, $(a,b) \in R \  \iff (b,a) \in R$. Therefore you have to add $(4,1),(5,1),(7,2),(6,3)$.

The last condition for $R$ to be a an equivalence relationship is that $R$ needs to be transitive, wich means for all $a,b,c \in R$, $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,c) \in R$ then $(a,c) \in R$ therefore you don't need to add any elements to $R$ because $R$ is already transitive.